# C# Generic Nullable Reference Type Arguments

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

Let's say I have a struct as follows:

```
public readonly struct Quantity<T> {
    public readonly T value;

    public Quantity(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

If I then have a method with the following signature:

```
void Foo(Quantity<string?> quantity) { ... }
```

Why does the following produce a `CS8620` warning, "Argument cannot be used for parameter due to differences in the nullability of reference types."?

```
Quantity<string> strQuantity = new Quantity<string>("Hello world");
Foo(strQuantity);
```

Or, rather, how do I avoid the warning? As I understand it, `string` and `string?` are the same types under the hood - and clearly in this case a `Quantity<string>` can be used anywhere a `Quantity<string?>` is required. So how do I indicate this to the compiler?

Some thoughts:

- Creating a new object (as in `new Quantity<string?>(strQuantity.value)`) feels a bit ridiculous, given that the underlying data would be identical, and therefore it's just a waste of time. For the same reason the compiler won't allow an explicit/implicit cast to be written for the `Quantity` struct.
- Is there some way around this if `Quantity` is a class rather than a struct?
- Do I need to go all the way to making a `IQuantity<out T>`, or something? Would that even help?

Comment: Does `Quantity` only ever hold reference types?

Comment: Ideally no, I have some `Quantity<int>`s in the codebase (or more complex equivalent). If it did, would `where T : class?` suffice?

Comment: I think that would work, yes.

Comment: You can call it like `Foo(strQuantity!);`.

Comment: why would you declare the method Foo with a fixed type instead of a generic type? `void Foo<T>(Quantity<T> quantity)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET JIT is pretty good at "unwrapping" structs of a single field. I wouldn't worry too much about creating extra instances of such structs.

`ImmutableArray<T>` is a common type with a similar problem, which it solves using the [CastUp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1.castup?view=net-7.0) method.

For the nullable case specifically, you can just use `!` to suppress the warning. You can consider wrapping the suppression in a method to make things more clear.

```cs
public static ImmutableArray<T?> AsArrayOfNullable<T>(this ImmutableArray<T> input) where T : class => input!;
```

There's also a csharplang discussion for possibly extending places where variant type parameters are permitted: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3950

Answer (score 1):

> clearly in this case a `Quantity<string>` can be used anywhere a `Quantity<string?>` is required

This is not true. If `Quantity<T>` had a setter on `Value` then `Foo` could set the value to `null`, even though you have declared it as `string` not `string?`. Because in the `Foo` function it only knows what it can see: `Quantity<string?>`.

And the compiler does not *know* that such a setter does not exist, and does not make any assumptions about what could be done with the nullability constraint on `T`.

Comment: In this case, as it is a `readonly struct`, the compiler can know that for the case of setters. However, you are right, it doesn't mean that other methods with the same issue could not exist. I'm just hoping there's some attribute or keyword that can be used to indicate that the `T` parameter allows variance under certain circumstances.

Comment: A readonly struct setter may be simply wrapping a setter on an underlying reference type which mutates the instance.

Comment: How would it mutate it? It can't hold a reference to it, and the struct itself cannot have mutators.

Comment: I could've been more clear here. Think `readonly struct RS<T> { MyClass<T> c; public T Value { get => c.Value; set => c.Value = value; }`.

Comment: Thats' a good point